# Stop a python program without signing out, Ctrl C, Alt F4, without use of mouse

Tags: python

I had a program that I tested (it was a game), but when I ran it, my mouse randomly teleported around the screen. Here's my code (I extracted the part that is the cause)

```
    import pygame
    import random

    from pygame.locals import *
    while True:
        global screen, white, zoom

        zoom = 1
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 1024))
        run = True
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(random.randint(0, 1024), random.randint(0, 1024))


        pygame.display.update()
```

How can I stop this code? I don't want to change the code. I tried using Ctrl C to keyboard interrupt, it didn't work. I tried using Alt F4, it didn't work. I don't have task manager. The only thing that did work is Ctrl Alt Delete (signing out), but I don't want to do that every time I need to stop a program. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Windows has a problem if you don't have task manager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should capture pygame events and check if the `QUIT` event is present, or, also, if the `K_ESCAPE` was pressed, then return from your `while True:`.

```py
quit = False
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                quit = True
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                quit = True
    if quit is True:
        return
```

Comment: I don't want to change the code though. I just want a way to exit if something goes wrong.

Comment: @mathwizard888 use Try&except ?

Comment: @mathwizard888 what do you mean you don't want to change the code?

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves He wants to exit the program without changing the source code (eg. Using task manager to force end task [Although he probably doesn't want to do so much things])

Comment: this is a 3yo question, and the answer marked as correct by the author. Not sure why you're notifying me?

Answer (score 0):

In game app, you can lose your control when update phase has too short period. Thus, I recommend that you create a thread for update phase written in your question and interleave `sleep` function call in while-loop. All of these approach will help you to prevent freezing of app.

Without freezing, Ctrl+C and Alt+F4 will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
```

and use `sys.exit()` wherever necessary if your program doesn't have any code after that code block.

```
>>> print sys.exit.__doc__
exit([status])

Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status).
If the status is omitted or None, it defaults to zero (i.e., success).
If the status is numeric, it will be used as the system exit status.
If it is another kind of object, it will be printed and the system
exit status will be one (i.e., failure).
```

Comment: As they are using pygame there is already a predefined way to do this, check my answer